Extend view into the background of another view in SwiftUI
I have a view where the top is a Map and the bottom is a rounded View, currently, when this screen is displayed, the Map view stops where the two view meets with a very obvious gap, Is there a way to seamlessly merge the two together so that the map appears as if it's in the background?
VStack {
    Map(position: $position) {
        UserAnnotation()
    }
    .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
    .ignoresSafeArea()

    List {
        ForEach(locationManager.debugMessages, id: \.self) { msg in
            Text(msg)
        }
    }
    .cornerRadius(30)
}



you could try using VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {...}

You can add the List as the safeAreaInset of the map.
Map {
    UserAnnotation()
}
.mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
    .cornerRadius(30)
    // the list takes up half of the available space
    .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical, count: 2, spacing: 10.0)
}
.ignoresSafeArea()

That said, IMO a better design is to make the List a constantly-presented sheet.
Map {
    UserAnnotation()
}
.mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
.sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
    .presentationCornerRadius(10)
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
    .interactiveDismissDisabled()
    .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
}
.ignoresSafeArea()


Actually. If I wanted to reverse the order, how would I go about doing it? i.e. if the map is on the bottom instead?

@bli00 .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) should work. Or add the map as a safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) of the List, depending on exactly what you want.

That worked, thanks! And if you don't mind me asking a follow up, how do I go about making this into something that's like a sheet but from the top? i.e. I would like to be able to dismiss the List by swiping up. Any pointers?

@bli00 That would be quite involved. You would need to re-invent your own sheet, add a DragGesture, and move the sheet with .offset.

I realized that this approach might have been a blunder and I should probably use a ZStack to achieve this effect. Surely, a drawer that comes from the top can’t be that hard to achieve?

@bli00 Well it's not hard, but it's also not trivial enough that I can tell you how to do it in a comment :) I'd suggest posting a new question if you are stuck.
